# Aligning Div tags to the same line

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to line up these three div elements so that the two column 1 boxes are on the left side stacked on top of each other and the column 2 box is on the right inline with the two column one boxes

I have tried all sorts of combinations of display:inline-block/inline and float:left;
but I just cant get these things to line up

```html
<div id="wrapper" width="auto">
  <div id="left-container" style="background-color:lightgray;width:10%;line- 
    height:95px;float:left;">
    column1
  </div>
  <div id="left-container" style="background-color:gray;width:10%;line-height:95px;">
    column1
  </div>
  <div id="left-container" style="background-color:lightblue;width:50%;line- 
    height:190px;">
    column2
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do not use inline css. Use a separate css stylesheet

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on the acceptable answers, because this would seem the perfect case for [CSS Grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Comment: Also don't use floats for layout anymore - with css3 there are much better ways tom do things - eg flex or grid

Comment: Also don't use duplicate id's. Baaaad practice.

Comment: And `width="auto"` as an attribute is an error too.And your `line-height`s have spaces in them. But can you change the HTML at all, or are you stuck with this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

You can work with `flex`.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  min-width: 10px;
}

.left-container:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 95px;
}

.left-container:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 95px;
}

.left-container:only-of-type {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" width="auto">

  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="left-container" style="">
      column1
    </div>
    <div class="left-container" style="">
      column1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="left-container" style="">
      column2
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! bonus points for taking my duplicate Id's (oops) and making them work with nth-of-type, I had no idea that was possible :O

Comment: @JimmyBoy I have updated my answer and check out this guide for [:nth-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/). Can be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

**css**

```
<style>
#wrapper > div{
display:inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: How does this achieve the OP's goal of having the two "column1" columns stack on the left?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to interchange the element, Please try like below structure.

```css
.left-container {
  float: left
}

.left-container>div {
  background-color: lightgray;
  line-height: 95px;
}

.right-container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 190px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" width="auto">
  <div class="left-container">
    <div>
      column1
    </div>
    <div>
      column1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-container">
    column2
  </div>
</div>
```

My Suggestion is try to avoid inline style and make class and add your styles over there. otherwise if you give your styles in the inline element, it is bit difficult to overwrite the style.

Answer (score 0):

I just write a basic flexbox example. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#left-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
}

#right-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
}

#left-container div,
#right-container div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" width="auto">
  <div id="left-container">
    <div style="background-color: lightgray; height: 20px;">
      column1
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: gray; height: 50px;">
      column1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-container">
    <div style="background-color: lightblue;">
      column2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Grid solution. Using [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) for specifying columns number and sizes for each column, then using [grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) and [grid-row](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) for specifying where the elements must be placed. The element with the class `third` takes two rows:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 50%;
}

.column-1 {
  background-color: gray;
}

.column-2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.first {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.second {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.third {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column-1 first">
    column1
  </div>
  <div class="column-1 second">
    column1
  </div>
  <div class="column-2 third">
    column2
  </div>
</div>
```